# First day of MonthCalendar1 selected year

Tags: vb.net

Following code gives last day of the previous month.

```
MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(-MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Day)
```

Which code gives first day of MonthCalendar1 selected year?

So if selected date is for example 13.06.2015 how to get 01.01.2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with your current method of adding negative days, simply subtract one from [DateTime.DayOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(-(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.DayOfYear-1))
```

If you want the last day of the selected year, use [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim dt As New DateTime(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year, 12, DateTime.DaysInMonth(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year, 12))
```

Comment: Thank you Idle_Mind. Solved. Similar question: If selected date is for example 13.06.2015 how to get 31.12.2015? So this time my question is about last day of MonthCalendar1 selected year. Please note that +365 doesnt work because some years consist of 366 days :-) `MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(-(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.DayOfYear - 1) + 365)`

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new Date using only the year of the reference date like This:

`Dim firstOfYearDate As Date = New Date(baseDate.Year, 1, 1)`

Like This

```
MonthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 365
MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = New Date(2015, 06, 13)
MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart = New Date(MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Year, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Are SelectionEnd and or SelectionStart are Date fields? And if so can they not be set to a new date value.

Comment: I added code that specifically uses the MonthCalendar Control